# React/JSX attrs w/strings vs braces

Tags: reactjs, jsx

The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#string-literals) say that a JSX attributes with strings are the same as attributes with braces...

`<Thing attr='val' /> === <Thing attr={'val'} />`

I thought I read something that said only use braces when needed because strings are more performant, but I can't find the reference now. Is there an evaluation cost for braces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an evaluation cost for braces

Yes, As you can see anything inside `{}` will be considered as javascript code, so that will be executed , if you just want to assign the string then
just simply use the `attr='val'` rather than `attr={'val'}`

but if you have assignment condition based then you can use `attr={'val'}`

like

```
attr={ (condition) ? 'val1' : 'val2'}
```

I Hope , this will clear your thoughts.

---

For more details :

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Here you can read behind the scenes of string interpolation and speed performance :

https://koukia.ca/string-interpolation-vs-string-format-string-concat-and-string-builder-performance-benchmarks-c1dad38032a

Comment: Thanks Vivek. Do you know of any reference material to back this up?

Comment: @ari, sorry didn't get you

Comment: "Anything inside `{}` will be considered javascript code", which means evaluation, which means performance hit; this was my thought too. But is there documentation/reference somewhere that mentions this? Or maybe somewhere I can benchmark the difference. I appreciate the string interpolation reference, but not what I'm looking for. thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

No there is no performance difference. Look at the code that's generated by each style:

```
<div first="abc" second={"def"}/>

// Compiles to:
React.createElement("div", { first: "abc", second: "def" });
```

Nicer to avoid unneeded braces though.

Answer (score 3):

JSX is actually parsing it to a JS object anyway, so it's either string creation overhead for the parser or string creation overhead in your component. It's trivial either way. With a string literal, though, it's just visually noisy in the code. It only really serves a purpose if the `val` is a variable or expression.

There is, however, a perfomance hit in a templating engine, such as that employed by the new interpolated strings. E.g.:

```
`It is a ${'cat'}`
```

would be slower than:

```
`It is a dog`
```

which should be slower still than just a plain literal:

```
'It is a dog'
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to find the interpolation part in the JSX engine. ;) https://github.com/jsx/JSX/tree/master/src