# React Native property values in quotes vs braces

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently learning React Native and wondering why some props have values in quotes `""` and some have their values in curly braces `{}`.

Is there a standard to when I should be using quotes vs braces?

```
<Button title="Press me" onPress={() => console.log("Hello")}/>
```

For example, in the line above the `title` is written using quotes but the `onPress` property uses the curly braces.

Comment: `title="Press me"` is basically the same thing as `title={'Press me'}`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React/JSX attrs w/strings vs braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276946/react-jsx-attrs-w-strings-vs-braces)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904825/what-do-curly-braces-mean-in-jsx-react

Answer (score 0):

**Quotes** are for when you're passing a simple string.

**Braces** are for when you want to run Javascript code. For example if you wanted to pass a variable as a prop, you'd need to use braces.

I personally try to use quotes whenever possible, but most of the times you need to use braces.